# No $T\in\mathcal{K}(X,Y)$ is onto

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, compactness, compact-operators

I have some struggles with this exercise.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be infinite dimensional Banach spaces. Show that no $T\in \mathcal{K}(X,Y)$ is onto.
We assume that $T\in \mathcal{K}(X,Y)$, so we have that $T\in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. I am thinking of showing this by contradiction, so I assume that T is onto, then I have by the open mapping theorem that T is open. Since we have that X,Y are Banach spaces, we have that they are normed vector spaces, and we have that T is open, then we have that  $B_Y(0,r)\subset T(B_X(0,1))$, then we'll have $\overline{B_Y(0,r)}\subset \overline{T(B_X(0,1))}$. Since we know that T is compact (since $T\in \mathcal{K}(X,Y)$) then we'll have that $\overline{T(B_X(0,1))}$ is compact hence $\overline{B_Y(0,r)}$ is compact. I am thinking that I will be done, if I can show that $\overline{B_Y(0,1)}$ is not compact, but I have trouble doing so.

Comment: The unit ball of a Banach space is compact if and only if the Banach space is finite dimensional.

Comment: Does it also hold for $\overline{B_Y(0,1)} $?

Comment: See [Riesz Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma).